# Which approach is better in Django Jsonfield or ForeignKey?

Tags: django

Such a question, I want to create a price comparison site, there are two ideas how to implement a list of prices from different stores.

First via ForeignKey

```
class Price(models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField()
    shop = models.CharField()

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    prices = models.ForeignKey()
```

JSONfield second method

```
class Product(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   data = JSONField()
   """ Product.objects.create(name='product', data={'price': 999, 
                                                    'shop': 'Amazon.com'}

  def __str__(self):
     return self.name
```

If anyone has experience, what works faster and more reliable if a large number of goods? Thanks for the early ones.

Comment: why would you want to refer price table from product. It feels weird. How about creating a table Product and create one more table called price which refers to the id or name of the product. Also, to your question, incase you wish to use JSON field, you would need an array of json because there might be multiple shops and each shops might have different prices[{'price': 999, 'shop': 'Amazon.com'},{'price': 9999, 'shop': 'ebay.com'}] which i think is unnecessary. The first one looks a lot cleaner and intuitive-just change the relation.

Comment: Yes i have  try my first method, it's work not correct. I have change the relation, but this don't work a = Product.obects.get(id=1), a.price_set.all(). I become a error.